# Best way to Web-scrape and inject JavaScript using React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-scraping, react-native, javascript-injection

I recently started using React Native to work on an app that involves web scraping. We've been using a component called the React Native WebView Bridge, which is similar to the UIWebViewBridge library in Obj-C but has some problems. Since React Native is asynchronous, we've been having trouble returning info in that the App calls the render function with the WebView Bridge often and unpredictably. Sometimes the WebView Bridge module will call our injected javascript 1 time, and sometimes it will call 3 times.

Is there a better way to scrape info and inject javascript effectively in React Native?

Here's a link to the [WebViewBridge](http://www.example.com/) for React Native that we used.

Answer (score 6):

I've used [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to parse HTML content from a website, transform it into JSON and use that to feed a React component. This way you get the benefits of using React Native, and not just a hybrid web app.

You can find an example of it in this React Native app: https://github.com/stan229/ClubReadyApp

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on manipulate? You won't be rendering the HTML to the DOM, but if you wanted to add some attributes (eg. class, id, change the innerHTML) you could. The workflow I follow, and generally would recommend (not knowing all the specifics in your case) is scrape the data you need from the HTML document, use that to render components and handle business interactions using React Native.

Comment: Sorry about that. What I mean by manipulate is can you inject javascript using this approach? For example clicking a button or inputting something to a text field. I would like to be able to do this without my injected script being called more than once by React's render method. Is that a bit clearer?